# Resulting request for input type="image" forms

Tags: html, forms, http, post, request

Web developers can use `<input type="image" name="name">` to present their users a graphical submit button. The [w3 standard on html forms regarding input controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) states that

> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is submitted and the click coordinates passed to the server. The x value is measured in pixels from the left of the image, and the y value in pixels from the top of the image. The submitted data includes name.x=x-value and name.y=y-value where "name" is the value of the name attribute, and x-value and y-value are the x and y coordinate values, respectively.

Now, I know that Firefox will generate a request that contains name itself, whereas Internet Explorer does not. my question, is Firefox providing additional functionality on top of the standard, does Internet Explorer not implement the full standard correctly (happened in the past …) or is the standard simply unclear regarding this aspect?

---

**edit**

It looks like Firefox creates a weird request (or it is parsed in a strange way by PHP). if the input name is an array (i.e. `name[1]`) the resulting `$_POST` variable will contain: `["name"] => array(1) { [1]=> string(2) "57" }`. so the .x component is munged and the .y component is turned into the only value …

---

**edit 2**

Upon further investigation it looks like even Firefox does not send the control's name when it's of type `image`, even with the value attribute set …

---

**addendum**

It seems like that what I really want to know is how I can make use of `<input type="image" name="el[]" />` elements when the name is an array, without messing up the POST request.

Comment: Try having form with `GET` method and you'll clearly see the data over the URL - can you spot anything helpful this way?

Comment: name is only send if it has a value, so <input type="image" src='..' name="..." value="submitted">. than name.x, namey and name will be send

Comment: is there no ['name.x'] ? got an URL to test?

Comment: @shadow wizard: yeah, that's actually a helpful pointer. with array suscripts the first (`.x`) will be overridden by the last component (`.y`). either the generated request is bogus or PHP has real problems parsing `n[10].x=192&n[10].y=60`

Comment: What happens when you have ordinary name like `btnSubmit`? Better luck with PHP?

Comment: @shadow wizard: i need array subscripts. and i don't care if the format is bogus, i'm only interested if the information is consistent and reliable between browsers

Comment: Hmm.. will have to test it myself somehow. By the way, when using `@` remove any blank spaces from the nick e.g. `@ShadowWizard` :)